# i have uploaded laravel project but it showing Index of /home in the browser. how can i fix it?

Tags: laravel, indexing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkC50.png)

project showing error after run it on browser. it shows index of/home. how to fix it?

Comment: You have to change your document root path to index.php in public folder

Comment: You are on shared hosting?

Comment: we are using laravel 8 and directory path is /opt/lampp/htdocs/home

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us if you are under Apache or Nginx please ?

In both case, you have to tell to your server to point to `/public` directory.

If you are under Apache, probably you have to configure it a little.

This [website](https://write.corbpie.com/how-to-fix-laravel-showing-the-directory-structure-on-apache/) gives some instructions on how to do this.

This shows you how to configure your apache website `conf` file to point to the right directory and how to activate it by restarting Apache.

Of course, to do this, you have to have access rights on your server.

Tell me if it helped you.

Have a nice day.

[laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel)